# MongoDB - Whats wrong with how I create index?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am trying to use Mongo's GeoSpatial features to locate documents based on coordinates. 
I need to create indexes for it to work - but it seems like I can't get the index created? Can you help?

I'll walk through what I have so far.

```
//User saves the location using a PUT Command. 
props.updateBandLocation({
        geometry: { 
            type: "Point", 
            coordinates: [ lat, lon ] 
        }
    })
```

Here is the route that puts it in the database. I try to get the index created here.

```
router.put('/:id',    (req, res) => {
quoteGenerator.findByIdAndUpdate({_id: req.params.id}, req.body).then(() => {
    quoteGenerator.findOne({_id: req.params.id}).then(generator => res.send(generator))
    quoteGenerator.createIndex( { bandLocation: "2dsphere" } )
})
```

})

The indexing throws an error in my terminal but it creates the location anyways. Here it is in the database.

```
//How the query looks in the database
    "bandLocation": {
    "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
            32.96179,
            -96.82916850000001
        ]
    }
},
```

Lastly, I am trying to get all the documents near a point using this route.

```
router.get('/allbands/:lat/:lng',   (req, res) => {
quoteGenerator.find(
    {
    bandLocation: 
        {   $near: {
                $geometry: {
                    type : "Point",
                    coordinates : [-req.params.lng, +req.params.lat],
                }
            }
        }
    }

  ).then(bands => res.json(bands))
```

});

Thanks for any help you have to offer!

Here is my schema --

```
    //Create GeoSchema 

const GeoSchema = new Schema({
    geometry: {
        type: {
            type: String,
            default: "Point",
            index: "2dsphere",

        },
        coordinates: {
            type: [Number],
        },
    } 
})

//Create Schema - Band
const AutoQuoteGeneratorSchema = new Schema({
    baseCost: {
        type: Number
    },
    mainDate: {
        type: Object
    },
    quoteGenerator: {
        type: Array,
        required: true,
    },
    userId: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    type: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    bandName: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    bandBio: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    bandLocation: GeoSchema,
    bandTour: {
        type: Array,
        required: true,
    },
    bandGenre: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    youtube: {
        type: Array,
        required: true,
    },
    published: {
        type: Boolean,
        required: true,
    },
    posts: {
        type: Array,
        required: true,
    },
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so from what i can see we have a couple of problems:

1. Structure:

From the 2dsphere index [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/2dsphere/):

> The 2dsphere index supports data stored as GeoJSON objects and legacy coordinate pairs

What type are [GeoJSON](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/geospatial-queries/#geospatial-geojson) objects?, they're `{ type: <GeoJSON type> , coordinates: <coordinates> }`

And what type are [legacy coordinates pairs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/geospatial-queries/#geospatial-legacy)? they're in the form of: `[<longitude>, <latitude> ]` or `{ <field1>: <x>, <field2>: <y> }`

So we can see `bandLocation` is neither, you need to use

```
quoteGenerator.createIndex( { "bandLocation.geometry": "2dsphere" } )
```

2. Your Coordinates are in the wrong order, You need to specify in the order of longitude then latitude. The valid range of latitude in degrees is -90 and +90. Your value of latitude of -96 is out of range.
   So change your document to `[-96.82916850000001, 32.96179]`.
3. Now we just need to adjust your query:

```
quoteGenerator.find({
    "bandLocation.geometry": 
        {   $near: {
                $geometry: {
                    type : "Point",
                    coordinates : [-req.params.lng, +req.params.lat],
                }
            }
        }
    })
```

** Another thing that pops up is that you create (try to create) an index every time there's a function call when in-fact you should only do it once. it should not be a part of your code. Now this won't throw an error but it's redundant as Mongo auto index documents on changes / inserts.

Comment: Hey Thanks for your response! I have re-formatted a bunch and I think I am on the right track - but - I dont know what happen... All of a sudden I cant create a new document - and I didn't mess with anything and I suddenly get an error - geo element must be an array or object: type: "Point". Would you be able to take a look at my schema above and let me know why all of a sudden this happened?

Comment: When you have an index built Mongo automatically tries to index new documents as they come in, specifically with a `2sphere` index if the field you're trying to insert does not match the required types (array of coordinates or geoelement type point) then it will throw an error, it will also throw an error if the coordinates are out of range (like i pointed out in my answer at topic number 2). this will cancel the insertion of the document.  why is this suddenly happening ? because for the first time ever you managed to properly build the index. up until now it didn't exist in the right format.

Comment: wow yes I just got it to post! I didnt change anything with the code - but I deleted everything in the database. Now it has created the document with the index. Going to try to use the GET request now.

Comment: I must not be doing the index right yet. hmmm Here is the error ---  unable to find index for $geoNear query

Comment: Assuming the index is built right, it means your query is not right i.e your trying to use `$near` with a field name that is not indexed. (like `bandLocation` should be `bandLocation.geometry` according to my example.

Comment: Ok! I am going to see if the index is built right - I believe that is probably still the problem... When I log into mongo I can see the Indexes - I see that it has the one for _id and now there is one for bandLocation.geometry.coordinates_2dsphere -

Comment: It was certainly the indexing. Thanks so much for your help. -- I never got the code to create the index for me and am uncertain why. It only worked after I went to mongoDB and used the gui to make the index.  Correct me if I am wrong, I only need to do it once?! I thought, with my newness to indexing, that it had to be done for each and every new document.  I'll remove the create index function from my code.  I guess, noramlly would you just create the index from the mongo shell or something like I did?  Thanks again for your help! It was a great chance to learn a bit more about mongo!

Comment: Hey Tom! Just curious - Could you point me to any documentation on adding a second indexed location to my route? Currently it only does the geo location on "bandLocation" but bands have the ability to add a tour location - "bandTour". I'd love all the results to come through one route if possible! Thanks again!

Comment: It sounds like you just want to use `$or` in your `find` query between the old field and the new one, apart from that there's no real difference between the setup of the new field.